# Firebase overwrites existing records instead of appending them

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a bit new to Firebase and so have been playing around with to help myself get more acquainted with it. So while I was playing around with realtime databases, I was trying to append data to the JSON tree. The code is as below

```
mSaudi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            count++;
            mHistory = mChildRef.child(Integer.toString(count));
            current = riyadh;
            mChildRef.setValue(riyadh);
            mHistory.push().setValue("riyadh");
        }
    });
```

The tree which I require is something like this:

```
value:   
 1: some text   
 2: some other text
```

But what's a actually happening is this:

```
value:
   1: some text
```

and on updation

```
value:
   2:some text
```

the previous entry gets erased

I have tried changing the references in various ways but to no avail. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a value on Firebase, it is going to replace everything in, and under the reference.

Let's say that you have a house value, with 2 childs: **Color** and **Size**.

If you want to edit only the color value, before the `setValue()`, you will have to change the reference you are pushing to.

If your reference was `getReference().child("houses")` and you push something there, it's going to replace everything there and below it. The way to do it is create a new reference (or update the previews one) like this: `getReference().child("houses").child(houseKey).child("color")` and push your String there.

In your example, you will need to add the field you want to change as a child before the `push()` method.

The other way was already told by **@Janwilx72** and is getting the whole object, updating the value locally and pushing the entire object again.

Comment: Getting the whole object, updating the value locally and pushing the entire object again. How about concurrent request?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to save both values, you have to save them using a variable such as a Hashmap. If you save a string and then try save another one under the same branch, it will delete everything previously saved. So try the following

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1","String");
map.put("2","String");
mHistory.push().setValue(map);
```

This will save both the strings without deleting one.

If you would only like to add one String

```
mHistory.push().child("1").setValue("Your first String");
```

The biggest problem with this though is that everytime you use push() you generate a random key, so you would have to save the key as a string and use it as a reference in your child.

Comment: This works but is it possible to add just the new element with Firebase other than having to push the entire HashMap as a new entry to the DB everytime a change has to be made?

Comment: @PrejithP Yes it's possible. The accepted answer shows how to do values individually

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`mChildRef.child("2").setValue("some text");`

It should be appending new item instead of overwriting them